# JSON Decode returning undefined index

Tags: php, html, arrays, json

I have a json file called articles.json and these are the contents:

```
{
  "articles": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "a"
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is the file where I am decoding it:

```
<?php
  include "inc/header.inc.php";

  $file = file_get_contents("articles.json");
  $arts = json_decode($file, true);
?>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Articles</h1>
</div>
<div class="grey">
  <div class="container">
  <?php
    foreach($arts as $article) {
      print_r($article);
      echo "<div class='part'>";
        echo "<div class='part-header'>".$article['title']."</div>";
      echo "</div>";
    }
  ?>
  </div>
</div>
<?php
  include "inc/footer.inc.php";
?>
```

And I get the following error: `Notice: Undefined index: title in /vagrant/www/ComputingEssentials/articles.php on line 19`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is still another dimension inside it. Its inside index zero:

```
echo "<div class='part-header'>".$article[0]['title']."</div>";
```

Or if you're expecting multiple articles, change the index origin:

```
foreach($arts['articles'] as $article) {
    echo "<div class='part'>";
        echo "<div class='part-header'>".$article['title']."</div>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: I wish to add multiple articles and cycle through them

Comment: @DaniyaalKhan then just nest another foreach on `article`, then just echo like you'd normally do

Comment: The problem is not the dimemsion inside it. The problem it's looping trough the wrong array.

Comment: @BartHaalstra who said the problem is the dimension? just access the right index

Comment: `foreach($arts as $article) { ` runs trough the 'container' object, not trough the articles array.

Answer (score 0):

change `$arts = json_decode($file, true);` to `$arts = json_decode($file)->articles;` And access your title like this: `$article->title`

If you have a good reason to keep using the data as assoc array use this:

```
$jsonData = json_decode($file, true);
$arts = $jsonData['articles'];
```

You can then access the title like this: `$article['title']`

Comment: But then, how do I access the title of the object?

Comment: Sorry, i missed the 2nd parameter of json_decode, remove it and work with it as objects instead of assoc arrays.